# MySQL - SQL select query with two tables using where, count and having

Tags: mysql, sql, select

There are two tables: `client` and `contract`.

*client table:*

```
client_code INT pk
status      VARCHAR
```

A client can have 1 or more contracts. The client has a status column which specifies if it has valid contracts - the values are 'active' or 'inactive'. The contract is specified for a client with *active* status.

*contract table:*

```
contract_code INT pk
client_code   INT pk
end_date      DATE
```

A contract has an end date. A contract end date before today is an expired contract.

REQUIREMENT: A report requires all active clients with contracts, but with all (not some) contracts having expired date. Some example data is shown below:

*Client data:*

```
client_code status
----------------------------------
1           active
2           inactive
3           active
4           active
```

*Contract data:*

```
contract_code   client_code   end_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
11              1             08-12-2018    
12              1             09-12-2018
13              1             10-12-2018
31              3             11-31-2018
32              3             10-30-2018
41              4             01-31-2019
42              4             12-31-2018
```

*Expected result:*

```
client_code
-------------
1
```

RESULT: This client (client_code = 1) has all contracts with expired dates: `08-12-2018`, `09-12-2018` and `10-12-2018`.

I need some help to write a SQL query to get this result. I am not sure what constructs I have to use - one can point out what I can try. The database is MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation.  We can join together the `client` and `contract` tables, then aggregate by client, checking that, for an active client, there exist no contract end dates which occur in the future.

```
SELECT
    c.client_code
FROM client c
INNER JOIN contract co
    ON c.client_code = co.client_code
WHERE
    c.status = 'active'
GROUP BY
    c.client_code
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN co.end_date > CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

### Demo

Note: I am assuming that your dates are appearing in `M-D-Y` format simply due to the particular formatting, and that `end_date` is actually a proper date column.  If instead you are storing your dates as text, then we might have to make a call to `STR_TO_DATE` to convert them to dates first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this and post back.

Comment: I need to be writing some queries in these lines - I can't look for answers online. I am not new to databases and just used to writing simple queries. Are there resources which I can refer to - books or online, specifically to MySQL.

Comment: SQL, like any language or most human endeavors, requires practice to master.  Honestly, participating in Stack Overflow is a great way to learn SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
select clients.client_code
from clients
join contracts
on contracts.client_code=clients.client_code
where status='active'
group by clients.client_code
having min(end_date)>curdate()
```